# I couldn't save price for product in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, module, product

```
 $p = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
       $p->setData("sku","real val sku111");
       $p->setData("name","real val name");
       $p->setData("price",21);
       $p->setData("custom_attr","real val");
       $p->save();
```

I couldn't save price with that code. It saves all other attribute value but when I check in admin panel, price column is always empty. I couldn't find out why. Could you help me?

Comment: You should probably check out a tutorial using "programatically create magento product" as you seem to be severely struggling with that. One such as this http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/ . There are many mandatory fields that you are not filling (attribute_set_id, type_id, tva class etc....)

Comment: yes i strugling with saving product. I saved successfully but still i have some problem such as i coudnt update or save qty , price doesnt save at first try, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setSku('testsku61')
    ->setName('test product21') 
   ->setPrice(21);
$product->save();
```